# How to find a certain variable value of another process in memory (in /proc/<pid>/mem )(in C#, at Linux)?

Tags: c#, linux, memory

A program S should do some log and stats about a certain variable of program V.
Both need to be written in C# and run at Linux.
The variable name and also its parents class name and also function names are known for program V. But it can't be changed to do some log itself.
Program S need to access the memory region of V from outside.
How to find a certain variable in there?

Due to answer to similar questions I think I got some code which reads the memory from outside:
Here some example code. For this test case S and V are combined in one program.
That means the program should read the value of one of its own variables through memory access.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace MemReadTest42
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public class TestClass42
        {
            public int randomVar42 { get; set; }
            public TestClass42()
            {
                //for example set it to a easy to search number
                randomVar42 = 12342000; //<--- Question: How to get this number from outside
            }
            public void incr()
            {
                //example function which  has impact at the variable
                randomVar42 = randomVar42 + 1;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // example variable
            Int32 myvari = 8777778; //<--- Question: How to get this number from outside

            TestClass42 exampObj = new TestClass42();

            Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); //(its this program itself)

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"/proc/" + process.Id + "/maps");
            string line;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {             

                string pattern = @"([0-9A-Fa-f]+)-([0-9A-Fa-f]+) ([-r])";
                Match m = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    string[] startend = (m.Value.Split(' '))[0].Split('-');
                    long start = Convert.ToInt64(startend[0], 16);
                    long end = Convert.ToInt64(startend[1], 16);
                    long len = end - start;

                    if (len > 0 && end > 0 && start > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"/proc/"+ process.Id+"/mem", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            fs.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                            byte[] b = new byte[end - start];
                            try {
                                fs.Read(b, 0, (int)(end - start));
                                string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
                                exampObj.incr();//some example var update
                                Console.WriteLine(s.Length + " " + s);
                            }
                            catch {
                                Console.WriteLine("FAILED");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            file.Close();   
            //use the example variables at the end
            Console.WriteLine(" end " + myvari + " " + exampObj.randomVar42);
        }
    }
}
```

1.) But where can I find those variables 'randomVar42' or 'myvari' ?
I stored the whole memory output in a file but it did neither contain the variable names nor their values.

2.) To narrow it down, in which map section should they be stored? in [heap], [stack] or that which has the program path? [vvar] could not be read during my test

Update: Question 2 was answered by Patrick Beynio in commends.
However in neither of those I could find a variable name or value.

Comment: If you're the owner of the target program, use an inter-process communication mechanism like a socket or shared memory.  If you're not the owner, I'm not going to say that it's impossible, but you don't even have access to Reflection values at the target process' level, and there are security implications to what you're attempting.

Comment: `randomVar42` is an class-instance property of type int, as a value type it will reside where it's defined, the instance, and class-instances are on the heap. `myvari` is an scoped int variable, again an value type so it resides where it's defined, variables live on the stack so it'll be on the stack

Comment: @RobertHarvey is this a special property of C#? It seems to work in Windos and other languages. For e.g. C in Windows ReadProcessMemory seems to work or for Linux process_vm_readv (not tested myself but written in other topic answers). 
Or with the Python script in [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux) I could found the variable name but not a value

Comment: @RobertHarvey real life owner or the user who runs the target program? I guess you meant first. That's not the case. I can not add any code or compile it again. But it will be the same user who runs those programs (at OS level).